# SWIG and Python3 Import Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, swig

I have written a library in C. I use [SWIG](http://swig.org) to generate bindings for Java, Python, etc. I managed to write custom type maps for both languages and so on. I also managed to use my library (a custom protocol) and communicate with a server that I wrote in C, with a client that I wrote in Java and, with a client that I'm writing in Python.

Recently, I came across a multiple inheritance problem with a [solution](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197-solving-the-metaclass-conflict/) I found smart. But, when trying to replicate the error using Python 3, the error was gone (*maybe* in version 3 is solved). The fact is that, the same code, the same project and the same source won't run invoking `python3` binary, but it works invoking python2.7 binary.

I get the message:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit__pytellapic)
```

Which I already read what could mean from SWIG documentation with a slightly different error:

```
import example
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_example)
```

Saying that:

> This error is almost always caused when a bad name is given to the
>   shared object file. For example, if you created a file example.so
>   instead of _example.so you would get this error. Alternatively, this
>   error could arise if the name of the module is inconsistent with the
>   module name supplied with the %module directive. Double-check the
>   interface to make sure the module name and the shared object filename
>   match. Another possible cause of this error is forgetting to link the
>   SWIG-generated wrapper code with the rest of your application when
>   creating the extension module.

Honestly, I think that this probable causes won't apply to my modules, as it should be an error for 2.7 and 3 versions of python, not just for Python 3.

I would appreciate any advice, but considering that SWIG seems to be an outdated project, probably I'll continuing using Python 2.7 with the mentioned "hack".

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the C module generated have a `PyInit__pytellapic` function defined?

The name and profile if the module init method has changed in Python 3. If you want the exact same C-code to run under both Python 2 and Python 3 you must include both the old and the new name. See the [Migrating C Extensions](http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html#module-initialization) chapter for more info.

According to [SWIG's documentation](http://swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_python3support) SWIG 2.0 should do this if you pass the -py3 parameter, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: In what -py3 parameter concern, I must say that I have tried it without success. I have also tried other flags listed in `swig -python -help` without luck. In a couple of minutes (maybe hours) i'm on that C extension reading. Thanks for your guidance and reply.

Comment: I add another comment for avoid mixing and doing a mess with this one. Answering your question, I've done a grep that results in: `#  define SWIG_init    PyInit__pytellapic` so honestly, I don't know why I get that error.

Comment: @Sebastian: Posting the code that SWIG generates might be helpful, but I suspect you need to ask on a SWIG mailing-list. You *seem* to be doing the correct thing judging from the documentation.

Comment: the C generated module wrap file has 11218 lines. I don't mind to post anything from my humble project as is GPL and available at google code, but for that I would suggest using some pastebin sites if noone minds about that.

Comment: I was going to paste the code, but I read [this](http://pastebin.com/MK0PLy3e) from the C wrap. I suspect that at compile-time `PY_VERSION_HEX` is less than `0x03000000`

Comment: @Sebastain: Oh well, you need to compile it under Python 3 for it to run under Python 3. :-) compiled libraries in Python are *not* version independent, you need one for Python 2.5, one for 2.6, one for 2.7, one for 3.1 and one for 3.2.

Comment: I assumed that cmake would compile it against the same version as the `python` (name without versioning) binary. I should now check my cmake files. I will be embarrased about my question if I found there the problem.

Comment: @Sebastian: cmake? I think you should use distutils, as usual, no? http://docs.python.org/distutils/examples.html#single-extension-module

Comment: well, my project involves all the things together. The C server, the Java client, the Python client, and the <Language> client that in who-knows-which future I will add to it. It's not restricted to python. CMake builds all the parts together. The C protocol library implementation, the C server, and the <Language> clients, linking all-together. I'm not familiar with distutils, is it worth it?

Comment: @Sebastian: If you want cmake to build the extensions, then you need to make your cmake compile the extension for all versions of Python you support. This can indeed be a good idea for Windows. For other platforms you need to make a source release that can be compiled on that platform. This should be done with distutils, really. The easiest way to make all the versions on Windows is probably to let cmake run `setup.py sdist` for each version of Python you want to support on Windows.

Comment: Yes, the purpouse of using CMake was to support portability. In fact, I had built a windows version too, and CMake has a SWIG module for compiling and linking the files. I've trusted in the 'automagic' thing, but seems that it's compiling against the wrong version. I would take your advices about distutils, and I'm really thankful about them. Also embarrased that my question was about how my project was being built.

Comment: well, I started the job. Still work to do. I've created a [configure_setup](http://code.google.com/p/tellapic/source/browse/trunk/src/swig/python/configure_setup.py) script that will receive input from CMake and will set some values in a file called `TellapicConfig.py`. The [setup.py](http://code.google.com/p/tellapic/source/browse/trunk/src/swig/python/setup.py) will import that file and use those values for setting up the project. I have ran successfully the script but still I have lot of work to do. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to resurrect the dead, but what how can I tell cmake to use python3 when the default /usr/bin/python points to python2? I have the same issue on my project but it is not clear how this particular issue was resolved in the end.