# swig and python3: surplus underscore

Tags: python, swig

Using swig 2.0.8 and python 3.2, running

```
swig -python -modern -py3 -o mymodule_wrap.c mymodule.i
```

produces a wrapper file that has

```
#  define SWIG_init    PyInit__mymodule
```

in there (note the two underscores between PyInit and mymodule).

Importing fails with

```
python3 -c "import mymodule"
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_mymodule)
```

(note the single underscore).

Manually deleting the underscore in `mymodule_wrap.c` and recompiling results in a working module.

In this question: [SWIG and Python3 Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845869/swig-and-python3-import-error) the python interpreter complained about not finding `PyInit__module`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the extension module is named `_mymodule.pyd` not `mymodule.pyd`.

#### Explanation:

Given a SWIG `.i` file containing the declaration:

```
%module mymodule
```

SWIG will generate two files:

- mymodule.py
- mymodule_wrap.c

`mymodule.py` is imported into Python via `import mymodule` and loads `_mymodule.pyd`.

`mymodule_wrap.c` contains an entry point function `PyInit__mymodule`.  This source file must be linked into the final `_mymodule.pyd`.

Python's `import <module>` statement looks for:

1. `<module>.pyd` with entry point `PyInit_<module>`.
2. `<module>.py`.

For a SWIG-generated extension, `import mymodule` will load `mymodule.py`, which loads `_mymodule.pyd` and looks correctly for `PyInit__mymodule`.

If the wrong extension name is used, `import mymodule` will load `mymodule.pyd` and look incorrectly for `PyInit_mymodule`.

Comment: Thank you! I was using distutils and changing the name of the Extension in `ext_modules=[ Extension('mymodule')]` to `ext_modules=[ Extension('_mymodule')]` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by passing `-interface <mod>` to swig, as in `swig -python -doxygen -py3 -c++ -cppext cpp -interface example_math interfaces/example_math.i`.

Then `import example_math` works after compiling it like `g++ -shared -fPIC src/example_math.cpp interfaces/example_math_wrap.cpp /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/libpython3.9.dylib -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -o example_math.so`.